# When a CSS Selector path doesn't work - what could it be?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking into changing all the download buttons from the website I manage...for that I downloaded the Easy Media Download plugin for Wordpress.
For custom styling, it allows you to add a Class.

So i have added the class "download" to it.

The download button which I am referring is the VIDEO one.

When I try to edit - for example:

```
.download {
    font-family: Qanelas, Arial !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

or

```
.emd_dl_blue.download {
    font-family: Qanelas, Arial !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

IT DOESN'T work...can some help me on this?
Have already tried dozens of different class selectors to try do style that button...

When I inspect the button the name of the class is "emd_dl_blue download"
So I try to select the element with:

.emd_dl_blue.download or .emd_dl_blue download...and other options..

But none work.

The selector path is:

> ## post-2057 > div.post-content > div:nth-child(6) > div > div.fusion-layout-column.fusion_builder_column.fusion_builder_column_2_3.fusion-two-third.fusion-column-last.\32 _3 > div > div.fusion-text > pre > a

The actual code of that button is:

```
<div class="fusion-text">
    <pre>  
        <a href="http://example.com/file.jpg" target="_blank" class="emd_dl_blue download">Baixar</a>  
        <style type="text/css>...</style>  
    </pre>  
</div>
```

Comment: Impossible to help you with this question. Sorry. This question should be closed. See **[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: I really don't trust those long links XD ... but I can bet your selector hasn't enough specificity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hello there, I have removed the link and added some more information on the situation. Anyway someone can help us get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the download button on your site and select inspect element, then look at what classes it has because it is generated by a plugin its probably got a few and then copy and paste the classes that it is using into your css and then add your custom styles..

so for example

```
.video-player.button.download{
    // your styles go here
}
```

Comment: Hey there A61NN5,
So...I already did that....but it doesn't work. there is a letter "a" before the element class...should I include that? I have already tried it too...but still doesn't work.

a.emd_dl_blue.download